# winforms C# using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, if-statement

```
private void fillcode()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANISH;Initial Catalog=HM;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string s = "select max(CustomerId) as Id from CustomerDetails";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        int i = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id"].ToString());
        sid.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am using this code, but there is a problem if there is no data in my table it will not accept.
So I want to use if no data is present it should take CustomerId as 1

Comment: Test to see if there are any ID's in the system. If there are none, then use 1. By the way, you should edit the title of your question to be more descriptive of your problem rather than a bunch of tags.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an incremented customer id based on the last highest value in that column in your table.  I would highly suggest letting SQL Server do this for you by setting the column as your `IDENTITY`.  It will do this for you in a much safer fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It will be `NULL` of there are no rows so you can:

```
"select isnull(max(CustomerId), 1) as Id from CustomerDetails"
```

You should also look at `ExecuteScalar` which is designed for a singe result.

Comment: Good! *But*... if he needs to write to the ID column later it will get tricky as performing `isnull` will make the column readonly.

Comment: Yes that's a good point, I assumed this was a read-only lookup.

Comment: I suggest to change the 1 to 0

Comment: Probably a safe assumption considering the probable function of the column, but you never know.  `ExecuteScalar` would be exactly what the OP needs to clean this up alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private void fillcode()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ANISH;Initial Catalog=HM;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string s = "select max(CustomerId) as Id from CustomerDetails";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id"].ToString());
            sid.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            sid.Text = "1"
        } 
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use the above code it doesn't work it is showing "Input String is not in correct Format" so can i do now